# Does DataSnapshot object contains all of its child data?

Tags: firebase

How will be the performance of **spanshot.numChildren()** when we have large number of children?

does firebase go through all of its children to count number of children or it maintains a **counter when a new child is added** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DataSnapshot contains all of the data locally in memory. Calling numChildren or anything else on a DataSnapshot will not result in any network I/O.

Note that this means you should be careful when generating those snapshots -- if all you want to do is count the number of something, loading a large DataSnapshot and then calling numChildren() is much more expensive than, for example, maintaining a separate count of the children and updating it with a transaction every time a new child is added.